Kubernetes filebeat config map for pod events
We have a pod that restarts randomly and we can't find the reason because Kubernetes only keeps event logs only for a short time. Even if we increase it, the logs will be lost when the pod is deleted.
Can someone help me out with the filebeat ConfigMap to log Kubernetes pod events in to Elasticsearch? I've tried different avenues but none of it worked.
I've tried with filebeat.inputs and filebeat.auto-discover but couldn't get it to work. I could get pod logs to be sent but that's not exactly what we need. We want to only send pod state events so that we can figure out what caused the restart and in the meantime to not flood elasticsearch with logs.
------------UPDATE------------------
As per Max Haase suggestion, I came up with the following,
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
      - type: kubernetes
        node: ${NODE_NAME}
        hints.enabled: true
        hints.default_config:
          type: container
          paths:
            - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log
        # This will collect Kubernetes events
        processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            in_cluster: true
        - drop_event:
            when:
              not:
                equals:
                  kubernetes.type: "event"

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
      index: "filebeat-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

    setup.template.name: "filebeat"
    setup.template.pattern: "filebeat-*"
    setup.ilm.enabled: false
    setup.template.overwrite: true

This is still logging the following error in the pod,
{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Cannot write to a field alias [agent.hostname]."}}

Any idea why?

It looks like there is an issue with the mapping in Elasticsearch. It seems to attempt to write data to a field that has been defined as an alias in Elasticsearch's mapping. Make sure that agent.hostname is not defined as an alias.
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_mapping"
I edited filebeat.yml
Rename processor changes the field name from agent.hostname to agent.original_hostname, avoiding conflicts with the field alias in Elasticsearch.
Reindex:
curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/_template/filebeat"
Then restart your Filebeat DaemonSet to apply the new configuration.

@MaxHaase your update worked. Thanks! Now the logs are being pushed to elastic. However, it's pushing everything. Not just the event types. Maybe something is wrong with drop_event? Also, how can I filter to log only the "default" namespace?

This is a common problem, it is my approach to log only K8s pod state events using Filebeat:

Configure: Use Filebeat’s autodiscover feature to detect pods and collect only state change events.
Filter Events: Use Filebeat processors to drop all events except those related to pod states.
Deploy: Set up Filebeat as a DaemonSet in your K8s cluster.
List item

That should ensure you capture relevant pod state events without flooding Elasticsearch with other logs.
Updated to rename or drop the problematic field:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
      - type: kubernetes
        node: ${NODE_NAME}
        hints.enabled: true
        hints.default_config:
          type: container
          paths:
            - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log
        # This will collect Kubernetes events
        processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            in_cluster: true
        - drop_event:
            when:
              not:
                equals:
                  kubernetes.type: "event"
        - rename:
            fields:
            - from: "agent.hostname"
              to: "agent.original_hostname"

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
      index: "filebeat-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

    setup.template.name: "filebeat"
    setup.template.pattern: "filebeat-*"
    setup.ilm.enabled: false
    setup.template.overwrite: true

The type: K8s input is used to collect K8s events.
The processors section adds K8s metadata to the events.
The drop_event processor ensures that only K8s events are sent to Elasticsearch by filtering out any other types of logs.
Next, deploy Filebeat as a DaemonSet so that it runs on all nodes in your cluster.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.12.0
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: "elasticsearch"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          subPath: filebeat.yml
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: filebeat-config

Filebeat needs permissions to access the K8s API to collect events. Create a ServiceAccount and ClusterRoleBinding for Filebeat if you ain't got one yet:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

Then, apply all the configurations to your cluster:
kubectl apply -f filebeat-configmap.yaml
kubectl apply -f filebeat-daemonset.yaml
kubectl apply -f filebeat-rbac.yaml


Thanks for you reply. However, you have mentioned to use auto-discover but in your example, you have used inputs right? I adjusted it and came up with a config using auto-discover. I have updated my original question with it. It's still giving an error. Do you have any idea why?
